# Java Pattern Matching in Extract content between parentheses

Tags: java, regex

Need to extract content between parentheses
for `(20)` - should return `20`
for `("creamy")` - should return `creamy`

I tried with the below pattern matcher but did not work. Can someone help?

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\((.*?)\\)");
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you encounter the compiler error on the single \? For that to compile in Java, you need to escape the backslash otherwise the compiler tries to find the special character (. So it should be:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\((.*?)\\)");
Matcher match = pattern.matcher("(cream)");
match.find();
System.out.println(match.group(1));
```

prints out

```
cream
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using regular expression in java. See code snippet below.

```
String matched = "";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\((.*?)\\)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("(20)");
if (matcher.find()) {
   matched = matcher.group(1);
}
System.out.println(matched);
```